# Gibt es andere Sätze wie "Wenn Fliegen hinter Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen hinterher"?

Tags: phrase, learning, curiosity, big-list

Man muss die Grammatik richtig verstanden haben, um diesen Satz zu verstehen: (zwei Varianten)

> Wenn Fliegen hinter Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen hinterher.
>
> Wenn hinter Fliegen Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen nach.

Gibt es andere spaßige Sätze wie diesen? (Keine Zungenbrecher, also Sätze die schwierig zu sagen sind, sondern Sätze, die schwierig zu verstehen sind.)

---

*Sie können meine Grammatik korrigieren, oder in* comments *anzeigen.*

Comment: "... die Grammatik richtig __verstehen__, um __diesen__ Satz...", "andere __spaßige__ Sätze __wie diesen__?"

Comment: Ich kenn den Satz so, dass sechs mal das Wort hintereinandersteht: Wenn vor Fliegen Fliegen fliegen fliegen Fliegen Fliegen hinterher.

Comment: Das beste Versmaß hat die Version: Wenn hinter Fliegen Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen nach.

Comment: *Wenn hinter Vögeln--* Ach nein, lassen wir das lieber. ^_^;;

Comment: @deceze, ich hatte mich nicht getraut ;-)

Comment: @deceze: Da sind aber nicht alles sechs Wörter gleich.

Comment: Doch, komm, @Deceze, wir wollen's hören! :)

Comment: Auf English: Is there a German equivalent of [buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)?

Comment: I was going to reference the same thing. I'll have to study that German expression later! :-) Mien Deutsch ist nicht so gut. :-(

Comment: Es funktioniert auch mit Hexen, Rollen und Kugeln.

Comment: [Tierende Tiere](https://andreas.schamanek.net/n/spr/tierende-tiere.htm) ist eine Liste von Tieren, die dieselben Konstruktionen wie bei Fliegen erlauben. Mangels Reputation hier nur als Kommentar verlinkt.

Answer (score 49):

Nicht hundertprozentig im Kontext der Frage, aber, finde ich, doch irgendwie passend (weil: fast nur zu verstehen, wenn man es langsam vorgelesen bekommt).

> In einem kleinen Dorf wohnte einst ein Mädchen mit dem Namen Barbara.
>
> Barbara war in der ganzen Gegend für ihren ausgezeichneten Rhabarberkuchen bekannt.
>
> Da jeder so gerne Barbaras Rhabarberkuchen aß, nannte man sie „Rhabarberbarbara“.
>
> Rhabarberbarbara merkte bald, dass sie mit ihrem Rhabarberkuchen Geld verdienen könnte.
> Daher eröffnete sie eine Bar: Die „Rhabarberbarbarabar“.
>
> Natürlich gab es in der Rhabarberbarbarabar bald Stammkunden.
> Die Bekanntesten unter ihnen, drei Barbaren, kamen so oft in die Rhabarberbarbarabar, um von Rhabarberbarbaras herrlichem Rhabarberkuchen zu essen, dass man sie kurz die „Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbaren“ nannte.
>
> Die Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbaren hatten wunderschöne dichte Bärte.
>
> Wenn die Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbaren ihren Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbart pflegten, gingen sie zum Barbier.
>
> Der einzige Barbier, der einen Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbart bearbeiten konnte, wollte das natürlich betonen und nannte sich „Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbier“.
>
> Der Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbier kannte von den Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbaren Rhabarberbarbaras herrlichen Rhabarberkuchen und trank dazu immer ein Bier, das er liebevoll „Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbier“ nannte.
>
> Das Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbier konnte man nur an einer ganz bestimmten Bar kaufen.
>
> Die Verkäuferin des Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbieres an der Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbierbar hieß Bärbel.
>
> Nach dem Stutzen des Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbarts ging der Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbier meist mit den Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbaren in die Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbierbar zu Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbierbarbärbel, um sie mit zur Rhabarberbarbarabar zu nehmen und mit etwas Rhabarberbarbarabarbarbarenbartbarbierbier von Rhabarberbarbaras herrlichen Rhabarberkuchen zu essen.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcMT395UvWI

Comment: Aufhören, sofort aufhören! :)

Comment: Und wegen Antworten wie diesen brauchen wir ein +10 Knöpfchen.

Comment: Coole Antwort, das kannte ich noch nicht.

Comment: Wahnsinn! Hab mich extra bei German.SX angemeldet um das mit einem +1 versehen zu können.

Answer (score 27):

> Selbst wer dort,
>   wo alles verkehrt verkehrt,
>   verkehrt verkehrt,
>   verkehrt verkehrt und wird bestraft.

Habe ich von [dieser](http://www.punctum.com/interest/language/zungen.de.html#repet) Seite.

Answer (score 21):

> Selten ess ich Essig. Ess ich Essig, ess ich Essig mit Salat.

und

> Mariechen sagt zu Mariechen,  lass
>   mich ma' riechen Mariechen,  da ließ
>   Mariechen Mariechen ma' riechen.

Comment: Schöne Dinger :)

Comment: Der erste funktioniert aber nicht im Süden ;) /es ix esik/ ;)

Answer (score 19):

Volksmund:

> Der Leutnant von Leuthen befahl seinen Leuten nicht eher zu läuten, als dass der Leutnant von Leuthen seinen Leuten das Läuten der Läuten von Leuthen befahl.

Ist natürlich eher mündlich interessant.

Answer (score 15):

Zwischen Müller und und und und und Co sind die Zwischenräume zu groß.

(Beschwerde des Herrn Müller beim Schildermacher.)

Comment: Das zeigt einfach nur die Wichtigkeit des korrekten Einsatzes von Anführungszeichen: »Zwischen „Müller“ und „und“ und „und“ und „Co“ sind die Zwischenräume zu groß.«

Comment: Ja, aber das würde hier den Effekt kaputtmachen.

Comment: Alternativ kaputtgemacht: `Zwischen Müller und & und & und Co sind die Zwischenräume zu groß.`

Comment: @starblue hat es einen Grund, dass du die Zitatformatierung mitentfernt hast?

Comment: Davon gibt es auch eine englische Version: "There needs to be more room between Pig and and and and and Whistle."

Answer (score 13):

Zwar phantasielos, aber trotzdem (der Vollständigkeit halber):

> Wenn vor Robben Robben robben, robben Robben Robben nach.

Comment: Um es in der Jugendsprache zu sagen: LOL ^^

Comment: Was bedeutet "robben" (verb)? Auf Englisch?

Comment: @BudgieInWA "robben" bedeuet "to crawl": *"If seals crawl in front of seals then seals crawl behind seals."* :)

Comment: @splathe: Wenn hinter Robben Robben robben übrigens auch. :)

Comment: Mit "vor" kann die Aussage falsch sein, wenn die hinteren Robben nur faul herumliegen anstatt den vorderen Robben hinterher zu robben. :-)

Comment: @BudgieInWA: It means pulling yourself forward while lying on the ground *without lifting your body from the ground*. I am not sure this can be translated as "to crawl", and if so, it has a more specific meaning than "to crawl", as "krabbeln" and "robben" are two different kinds of movements.

Comment: @starblue: Ich wäre nicht selbst darauf gekommen, aber Dein Kommentar hat mich zum Nachdenken angeregt, und nun befürchte ich ein ähnliches Dilemma mit "hinter": Hier wäre es möglich, daß die vorderen Robben nur faul herumliegen, anstatt den hinteren Robben voranzurobben. Dann wäre die Aussage ebenfalls falsch.

Comment: @Binarus Das kann aber nicht lange gutgehen.

Answer (score 12):

> Denke nie, du denkst, denn, wenn du
>   denkst, du denkst, dann denkst du
>   nicht, dann denkst du nur, du denkst,
>   denn das Denken der Gedanken ist
>   gedankenloses Denken.

Answer (score 12):

> Wenn die *Nachkommen* mit dem *Einkommen* der *Vorkommen* nicht *auskommen*, werden sie *umkommen*!

Comment: Das finde ich nett!

Comment: Der Vorkommen? Sollen das Ahnen sein? Ansonsten ja, nett.

Comment: Alternativvorschlag: Es kann Vorkommen, dass die Nachkommen mit dem Einkommen nicht auskommen.

Answer (score 12):

Von Konrad Duden persönlich stammt:

> Die, die die, die die Dietriche erfunden haben, verdammen, tun unrecht.

Hintergrund: http://www.gfds.de/publikationen/rezensionen/konrad-duden-schreibe-wie-du-sprichst/

Answer (score 12):

Dialog zwischen einem Passanten und einer Mutter mit kleinem Kind in Köln (das Kind polkt Putz von der Wand):

> Darf dat dat?
>   Dat darf dat.
>   Dat dat dat darf!

(Darf das (Kind) das? Das darf das. Dass das das darf!)

Comment: "Das Kind *polkt* Putz von der Wand" – kommt da die Polka her? :-)

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/polken

Comment: Danke für den Link.

Answer (score 11):

Mein eigener:

> Wenn das die Wüste wüsste,
>   wie das Meer die Küste küsste.

Comment: There is an audible difference between "Wüste" and "wüsste", though (the very same difference that is reflected by the difference in spelling).

Answer (score 11):

> Wenn ich die See seh, brauch ich kein Meer mehr.

Answer (score 10):

Otto Waalkes sagte einst:

> Du hast geglaubt, Du gehörst zu denen, denen Dänen alles durchgehen lassen

und

> Wasser wartet ... Was? Er wartet? ... Ahhh! Was erwartet ...

Comment: "Was, willst Du schon *wieder*?" versus "Was *wills*t Du schon wieder?" versus "Was willst *Du* schon wieder?" versus "Was willst Du *schon* wieder?"...

Comment: Da war aber Hansjörg Felmy in "Wir Wunderkinder" früher dran: "So gut geht es denen, denen Dänen nahestehen".

Comment: ... Daenen luegen nicht!

Answer (score 10):

Wirklich wahr: In Krems an der Donau gibt es ein Kloster mit dem Namen „Und“: http://www.klosterund.at/

Es hat diese Adresse (auch das ist die volle Wahrheit):

> Kloster Und
>   Undstraße 6
>   3504 Krems/Stein
>   Austria

Es gibt in dieser Postadresse also zwischen *Und* und *Undstraße* einen Zeilenumbruch.

Sehen wir uns den letzten Satz an. Er enthält mehrere Wortzwischenräume, nämlich unter anderem je einen zwischen *zwischen* und *Und*, *Und* und *und* und *und* und *Undstraße*.

Answer (score 8):

Ich kenne noch

> Ich weiß, dass das das Dass ist, das man mit Doppel-s schreibt.

Comment: +1 Inhaltlich allerdings ist der Satz aber nicht richtig, oder? Das ist nicht das Das, das man mit Doppel-s schreibt. :)

Comment: Stimmt, eigentlich ist es das Dass, das man mit Doppel-s schreibt ^^

Answer (score 8):

Wie wär's mit sechs Mal "die"?

> Wir spielen jetzt eine Melodie, die
>   die, die die diesjährige Sendung
>   "Unser Song für Europa" nicht gesehen
>   haben, vermutlich nicht kennen werden.

Comment: (Naja, zwar französisch, aber auch nett: `Si six scies scient six cyprès, six cent six scies scient six cent six cyprès`.)

Comment: Ces cent sons sont sans sens. (Diese hundert Töne sind ohne Sinn.)

Answer (score 7):

> Wenn Grillen Grillen grillen, grillen Grillen Grillen.

Comment: Also killen Grillen Grillen durch grillen ...

Answer (score 6):

> der gefangene floh

Ich habe hier alles klein geschrieben, da die Zweideutigkeit sonst nur mündlich funktioniert.

Comment: Ich kapiers nich oO"

Comment: "Der Gefangene floh." oder "der gefangene Floh"

Comment: Aaaaah.... *bing* hats gemacht... Sehr geil :D

Comment: Genau wie Englisch: "the prisoner fleas" vs "the prisoner flees".

Comment: @ApoY2k: Bing hat's gemacht? Seit wann macht es denn Bing? Ich meine es macht irgendwie anders, aber jetzt klingelt es bei mir nicht. ... und es hat Boum gemacht ist das eine, aber klingeln ist wieder anders.

Comment: Das mit dem Boum könnte man mal bei Bing googeln.

Comment: Dann liegt mir noch auf der Zunge: "ach! wär er doch nur dichter!"

Comment: @thei: Das ist nett, aber von anderer Art, denke ich. Meine Lieblingsversion: Helft den armen Vögeln (oder die andere Variante `:-)`)

Comment: Übrigens ist das zwar auch ein Wortspiel, passt aber m.E. hier nicht rein und gehört gelöscht oder abgewertet.

Answer (score 6):

Klingt besser als es aussieht:

> Wenn hinter Griechen Griechen kriechen, kriechen Griechen Griechen nach.

Vom Rhythmus empfehle ich "Wenn hinter x x x, x x x nach." überhaupt, also auch bei Robben und Fliegen.

*Das folgende ist etwas geschmacklos*:

> "Wenn hinter Reihern Reiher reihern, reihern Reiher Reihern nach."

Ich bitte um Vergebung, aber was tut man nicht, im Namen der dt. Sprache.

Comment: Ich finde das erste viiiiiiel geschmackloser! Aber im Namen des Wikis...

Answer (score 5):

> Wenn Bienen sich zu Bienen beamen, beamen Bienen sich zu Bienen.

> Denke nie gedacht zu haben, denn das Denken der Gedanken ist gedankenloses Denken. Denkst du doch, du denkst, dann denkst du nur du denkst, denn denken, denke dran, denken tust du nie!

> Wer nichts weiß, aber weiß, dass er nichts weiß, weiß mehr als der, der nicht weiß, aber nicht weiß, dass er nichts weiß.

Answer (score 5):

Da fällt mir ein Merksatz aus der Mittelschule ein:

> Wer "brauchen" ohne "zu" gebraucht, braucht "brauchen" gar nicht zu
>   gebrauchen.

Answer (score 4):

> Das Leben meint es gut mit Dänen und mit denen, denen Dänen nahe stehen.

und meine Signatur in diversen Foren:

> Wäre der Satz "Ich möchte auf meinem Fisch-und-Chips-Schild einen Bindestrich zwischen die Wörter Fisch und und und "und und Chips machen" nicht deutlicher, wenn Anführungszeichen vor Fisch und zwischen Fisch und "und" und "und" und "und" und "und" und "und" und "und" und "und" und "und" und "und" und "und" und Chips und auch nach Chips wären?

Comment: Tim Pietzcker hatte die Dänen schon, und Starblue hatte die und schon vorgestellt, wenn auch nicht so extrem. Man sieht jetzt aber, dass man zwischen Fisch und und und ... und und und Chips immer weitere Änderungen diskutieren kann - endlos.

Comment: Ich finde es angemessen, eine bessere Version einer bereits gegebenen Antwort zu geben.

Comment: Soll da wirklich ein `"` in `Fisch und und und "und und Chips machen` sein??

Answer (score 4):

Nach dem Muster der Frage:

> Wenn hinter Wogen wogen wogen, wogen Wogen Wogen hinterher.

Eine ganz andere Schiene wäre:

> Mähn Äbte Heu? Nee, Äbte mähn nie Heu, Äbte beten.

Beim Lesen völlig unproblematisch, wenn man den Satz aber nur hört werden >90% der Muttersprachler nicht erkennen, dass es sich um deutsche Sätze handelt.

Comment: Die "ganz andere Schiene" ist aber auch wirklich etwas _ganz_ anderes und hat wenig mit der Frage zu tun (so schön es auch ist, diesen Satz an seinen Zeitgenossen auszuprobieren).

Comment: Ich kenne diese Version: "Mähen Äbte Klee? Äbte mähen nie Klee. Äbte beten."

Comment: Ich kenne den so: "Mähn Äbte Heu? Nie mähn Äbte Heu! Wenn Äbte mähn, mähn Äbte Gras."

Answer (score 3):

> Ladenbesitzer, die vor einem Schokoladenladenrollladen Schokoladen laden, laden Ladendiebe zum Aufladen von Schokoladen hinter dem Schokoladenladenrollladen im Laden ein.

Etwas gestelzt, aber dafür noch unbekannt.

Comment: Ich kenne das etwas anders: *Männer, die vorm Schokoladenladen laden, laden Ladenmädchen ein.*

Answer (score 3):

Ein Spruch, der im Herbst 1989, also kurz vor der Wende in der DDR, in (Ost-)Berlin irgendwo im U-Bahnhof Alexanderplatz zu lesen gewesen sein soll, vgl. [dieses Bild](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=569987039678870&set=a.341335185877391.91674.213775278633383&type=1&relevant_count=4):

> Wenn ich nur darf, wenn ich soll, aber nie kann, wenn ich will, dann mag ich auch nicht, wenn ich muss. Wenn ich aber darf, wenn ich will, dann mag ich auch, wenn ich soll, und dann kann ich auch, wenn ich muss. Denn schließlich: Die können sollen, müssen wollen dürfen.

<sup>(Rechtschreibung an neue Schreibung angepasst, Kommafehler repariert)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Im Grunde suchst du dennoch [Zungenbrecher](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zungenbrecher)? Es gibt einfachere und schwierigere.

Ganz ähnlich wie dein erstes:

> Wenn Griechen hinter Griechen kriechen, kriechen Griechen Griechen
>   nach.

Oder ein sehr bekanntes in der deutschen Sprache

> Fischers Fritz fischt frische Fische, frische Fische fischt
>   Fischers Fritz.

Comment: Es geht dem Fragenden doch eben _nicht_ um Zungenbrecher - ich würde die Sache mit den Fliegen auch nicht als Zungenbrecher bezeichnen. (Das mit den Griechen gab's übrigens schon in einer anderen Antwort.)

Comment: Ich weiss, allerdings fällt der Satz mit den Fliegen in die Kategorie Zungenbrecher. Und es gibt eben mehrere leichte Zungenbrecher, die so aufgebaut sind. -- siehe Link

Comment: Ah, ich bin Deinem Link nicht gefolgt! Es ist auf Wikipedia also in der Tat als Zungenbrecher klassifiziert - na gut.

Comment: @Lumio: Kannst Du eine verlässliche Quelle dafür angeben, dass der Satz mit den Fliegen ein Zungenbrecher sei? Meines Erachtens ist ein Zungenbrecher ein Satz, der schwer auszusprechen ist, weil er viele ähnliche, aber eben *nicht* gleiche Wörter enthält (wie z.B. der berühmte "Fischers Fritz"). Der Fliegen-Satz hingegen ist trivial auszusprechen, aber nicht leicht zu verstehen, weil eben gerade identisch ausgesprochene Wörter aneinandergereiht werden. (Und nein, die Auflistung in Wikipedia ist für mich keine verlässliche Quelle, insbesondere wenn er von einer IP hinzugefügt wurde.)

Comment: Der wurde schon gepostet. Und ist boes (schmoll)

Answer (score 2):

Aus dem Bairischen:

> Des a Krux mit de Bam. *Dadadiadada, dadadiadadara und dadadadadaradadiara.*

(Aus Lust und Laune in den letzten dreien auf Wortzwischenräume verzichtet.)

(Ausgesprochen gibt es leider zwischen *a* und *a* einen Unterschied, aber Preußen hören den oft nicht raus.)

Die Übersetzung:

> Das ist schlimm mit den Bäumen. Da geht er dir ein, da geht er dir auch ein und da täte er dir auch eingehen.

Comment: Was ist das Wort für _eingehen_? Hat es ein standardsprachliches Kognat?

Comment: @chirlu dadiara. Nach dem Kognat bin ich überfragt.

Answer (score 2):

Etwas spät dran:

> Bismark biss Mark, bis Mark Bismark biss.

Answer (score 0):

Hier kommt ein Satz, der wirklich so gesagt worden ist.

In der Wuppertaler Schwebebahn sitzt ein kleines Mädchen und ißt ein Eis. Viel davon fällt dabei auf den Boden. Ein anderer Passagier wundert sich:

> Dat dat dat darf.

Anmerkung: Im Wuppertaler Dialekt sagt man *dat* anstelle von *das* und *daß*, und man muß sich den Satz schnell gesprochen vorstellen.

Comment: Wirf mal einen Block auf diese Antwort: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/1087 :-)

Comment: @Martin Peters Could you please replace "dat's" in the above sentence "Dat dat dat darf." with 'das' and 'daß', as appropriate? I sense it's funny, but still don't get the catch.

Comment: Dass das das darf?! --> Dass das Kind so etwas darf?!

Answer (score 0):

Einer, der mir einst als Kind eingefallen ist, in größtmöglicher Analogie zum Satz des Fragestellers:

> Wenn hinter Rollen Rollen rollen, rollen Rollen Rollen nach.

Eventuell ist auch dies akzeptabel (wenngleich das Wort *kugeln* als Verb einen schalen umgangssprachlichen Beigeschmack haben könnte):

> Wenn hinter Kugeln Kugeln kugeln, kugeln Kugeln Kugeln nach.

Wenn man (zugegebenermaßen etwas unrealistisch) unterstellt, daß Fliegen bewußt handelnde Subjekte sind und für ihre Artgenossen gerne Dienstleistungen (zum Beispiel in Form von Mitflug-Gelegenheiten) erbringen, so ist sogar eine achtfache Verwendung möglich:

> Wenn hinter Fliegen Fliegen Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen Fliegen nach

(Im Sinne von "Das Flugzeug fliegt Gepäck." und "Das Flugzeug fliegt das Gepäck nach.".)

Answer (score 0):

Anlässlich des (fiktiven) "Sexy-Ass-Contests" in Posen (Polen):

> Wenn in Posen (Polen) Pos hinter Pos posen, posen in Posen (Polen) Pos hinter Pos.

(Wer noch einen Posaunenchor unterbringt, kriegt einen Keks)

Dort gibt's auch die eher aussichtslosen Teilnehmerinnen (weil's immer noch ein bisschen alberner geht):

> Potentiell reicht das Posen von porigen Pos in Posen (Polen) nur für die hinteren Positionen

Ähnliches Thema, diesmal aber eher Gedränge bei der Adipositas-Selbsthilfegruppe im tiefsten Allgäu:

> Wenn hinter Hindelang Hintern hinter Hintern hindern, hindern hinter Hindelang Hintern hinter Hintern.

Nur für Segler:

> Wenn das Vorfall vor fällt, ist ein Vorfall vorgefallen.

Nur für Franken, wenn der Vater dem Sohn ein bisschen Sprit vom Tankstellenbesitzer mit dem altmodischen Namen spendiert (hier begebe ich mich wahrscheinlich auf zu dünnes Eis):

> "Ich danke dir". "Beim Dankwart Dankwart?". "Ja." "Danke dir."

Und wenn wir schon bei der Mundart sind, noch einer (nur ein ähnlicher) aus dem Schwäbischen:

> Wegga wem send d'Wegga weg?
>
> Send älle älle?
>
> Wer war do do?