# Examples of texts with very long words

Tags: compound

I'm interested in examples of texts that contain large numbers of long German words. It is basically just for testing purposes, still I would prefer the text to make at least some sense. If it were couple paragraphs, I would be most happy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A place to look for long compounds in a complicated context may be the legislative texts. These can openly be accessed via the following link

- [Gesetze im Internet](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/)

One such example using excessive long compounds is the "[Finanzmarktstabilisierungsfondsgesetz](http://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Gesetzestexte/Gesetze_Verordnungen/Finanzmarktstabilisierungsfondsgesetz.html)":

> *... Finanzmarktstabilisierungsbeschleunigungsgesetzes sowie § 5 Absatz 2 und 5 bis 9 der Finanzmarktstabilisierungsfonds-Verordnung in der am 23. Juli 2009 geltenden Fassung gelten für die Garantiegewährung nach Absatz 1 entsprechend. § 5 Absatz 2 Nummer 5 der Finanzmarktstabilisierungsfonds-Verordnung findet jedoch vorbehaltlich der Zahlung der Ausgleichsbeträge nach den §§ 6b und 6c auf Dividenden und Gewinnausschüttungen an die Anteilseigner keine Anwendung. ...*

Of course there are paragraphs or laws using less elaborate compounds but usually we will find plenty of creative examples of overlong compounds in these  legal wordings.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a whole story for you:

[Am Schneesee](http://www.schneeseekleerehfeedrehzehwehvergehtee.de/) by Franz Fühmann.

It's also a really fun tongue twister.

Comment: Not to forget: [Rhabarberbarbara](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/914/1932).

Answer (score 6):

Some time ago I collected several mostly German dummy/filler texts (in German called “Blindtexte”). Some of them contain longer compound words. Maybe they are too short for your purpose, but see yourself: http://speravir.website.org/files/latex/blindtext/blindtext.pdf (it actually started as a finger exercise for LaTeX).

Another one found here on German.SE and containing some long words: [Rhabarberbarbara](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/914/1932).

Searching for single long words I found this:

- Not to be taken very serious, as the domain shows: [Stupidedia: Längstes Wort der deutschen Sprache](http://www.stupidedia.org/stupi/L%C3%A4ngstes_Wort_der_deutschen_Sprache) (German). But for testing purposes it could be perfect. ;-)
- A real case word: [Wikipedia: Rinderkennzeichnungs- und Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rinderkennzeichnungs-_und_Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz) (English). In the article an even longer word is mentioned: “Grundstücks­verkehrs­genehmigungs­zuständigkeits­übertragungs­verordnung”, this is also real and comes from the legal area as well.

  On the bottom an article for a much more famous word is linked, too: “Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft‌”.
- Another source for long compound words is [Wikipedia: Isogramm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogramm) (German).

Comment: Shall Rinder-something be the new Donau-something. I never liked Donau something because it doesn't feel like a real word to me. It feels made up for the purpose of funny. The Rinder-one however is spot on German law lingo :) +1

Comment: :-) Siehe auch Deutsche Wikipedia: [Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz) „Von 1992 bis 1996 stand im Guinness-Buch der Rekorde die Donau­dampfschiffahrts­elektrizitäten­hauptbetriebswerk­bauunterbeamten­gesellschaft, deren Existenz aber fraglich ist.“ Und ebenso [Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapit%C3%A4n).

Comment: I just now met in a real-world bureaucratic context *Personalisierungsinfrastrukturkomponente*. Surprisingly this is meant to mean a certain unit of the police where staff of the the Federal Office for Asylum Seekers and Refugees are deployed. I suppose it is called that difficultly in order to prevent asylum seekers finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I just now stumbled upon a transcript of a conversation in a business setting (managers talking to academics) and found this:

> A1: Das denkt im Grunde unser Leserpublikum natürlich mit, dass die Methodik eine solche ist, dass einzelne Zitate keinen **Verallgemeinerbarkeitsanspruch** haben. Aber dass diese Aspekte eine Rolle spielen können in einem Einzelfall und da dann auch entsprechende Effekte haben, das zeigt sich halt da. Mehr aber nicht.
>
> A2: Insbesondere, wenn es um Zahlen geht, was der **Geschäftsberichtserstellungsprozess** gekostet hat. Da in Ihrer Fußnote. Die waren ja grausam. (1:14:11)